# jTable Head Section Files

Tags: jquery, jtable

I am working on `creating a table` form using `jTable plugin`. I'm trying to implement it with PHP. I'v Downloaded the example files and it works very OK.

**The problem is:** when I execute the code the table hasn't the  `"go to page area"`.
I tried solve the problem changing the the Head Section Files of the Html in the Client Side code. So I download the last version of jquery, jquery-ui and  jtable.
I'm not sure if the problem is on the client side code or in the files Jquery, jquery-ui It respects on .css and .js files that I'v downloaded.

this is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link href="Scripts/jtable/themes/lightcolor/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="PeopleTableContainer" style="width: 600px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Prepare jTable
            $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Table of people',
                paging: true,
                pageSize: 2,
                gotoPageArea: 'combobox',
                pageSizes: {10,25,50,100,250,500},
                pageSizeChangeArea: true,
                sorting: true,
                defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
                actions: {
                    listAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=list',
                    createAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=create',
                    updateAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=update',
                    deleteAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=delete'
                },              
                fields: {
                    PersonId: {
                        key: true,
                        create: false,
                        edit: false,
                        list: false
                    },
                    Name: {
                        title: 'Author Name',
                        width: '40%'
                    },
                    Age: {
                        title: 'Age',
                        width: '20%'
                    },
                    RecordDate: {
                        title: 'Record date',
                        width: '30%',
                        type: 'date',
                        create: false,
                        edit: false
                    }
                }
            });

            //Load person list from server
            $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load');

        });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason of that the files of the example to downloading, dont respond to the command "goToPageArea" is cause on the theme, some themes havent that function. To solve my problem i'v downloaded the theme-files direct from author-syte.